# Trying to understand a Tensorflow cuDNN error

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.6, recurrent-neural-network, cudnn

I recently downloaded cuDNN and am getting some errors. My model starts training but then it quickly dies out. If I have a smaller network it will train for longer before dying out I want to try to understand if they are GPU OOM related or something else.

I am using Tensorflow 1.15.2 and cuDNN 7.6.5 w/ Cuda 10.0

Errors:

```
Epoch 0 |   Training | Elapsed Time: 0:00:00 | Steps: 0 | Loss: 0.000000
Epoch 0 |   Training | Elapsed Time: 0:00:01 | Steps: 1 | Loss: 49.104568
Epoch 0 |   Training | Elapsed Time: 0:00:02 | Steps: 2 | Loss: 54.958607
Epoch 0 |   Training | Elapsed Time: 0:00:02 | Steps: 3 | Loss: 46.999936
Epoch 0 |   Training | Elapsed Time: 0:00:02 | Steps: 4 | Loss: 69.989386
Epoch 0 |   Training | Elapsed Time: 0:00:02 | Steps: 5 | Loss: 67.471436
Epoch 0 |   Training | Elapsed Time: 0:00:02 | Steps: 6 | Loss: 66.270167
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1365, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1350, in _run_fn
    target_list, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1443, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Internal: Failed to call ThenRnnBackward with model config: [rnn_mode, rnn_input_mode, rnn_direction_mode]: 2, 0, 0 , [num_layers, input_size, num_units, dir_count, max_seq_length, batch_size, cell_num_units]: [1, 2048, 2048, 1, 24, 4, 2048]
         [[{{node tower_0/gradients/tower_0/cudnn_lstm/CudnnRNNV3_grad/CudnnRNNBackpropV3}}]]
  (1) Internal: Failed to call ThenRnnBackward with model config: [rnn_mode, rnn_input_mode, rnn_direction_mode]: 2, 0, 0 , [num_layers, input_size, num_units, dir_count, max_seq_length, batch_size, cell_num_units]: [1, 2048, 2048, 1, 24, 4, 2048]
         [[{{node tower_0/gradients/tower_0/cudnn_lstm/CudnnRNNV3_grad/CudnnRNNBackpropV3}}]]
         [[tower_0/gradients/tower_0/cudnn_lstm/CudnnRNNV3_grad/CudnnRNNBackpropV3/_69]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DeepSpeech.py", line 12, in <module>
    ds_train.run_script()
  File "/DeepSpeech/training/deepspeech_training/train.py", line 955, in run_script
    absl.app.run(main)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 299, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 250, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/DeepSpeech/training/deepspeech_training/train.py", line 927, in main
    train()
  File "/DeepSpeech/training/deepspeech_training/train.py", line 595, in train
    train_loss, _ = run_set('train', epoch, train_init_op)
  File "/DeepSpeech/training/deepspeech_training/train.py", line 560, in run_set
    feed_dict=feed_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 956, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1180, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1359, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1384, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Internal: Failed to call ThenRnnBackward with model config: [rnn_mode, rnn_input_mode, rnn_direction_mode]: 2, 0, 0 , [num_layers, input_size, num_units, dir_count, max_seq_length, batch_size, cell_num_units]: [1, 2048, 2048, 1, 24, 4, 2048]
         [[node tower_0/gradients/tower_0/cudnn_lstm/CudnnRNNV3_grad/CudnnRNNBackpropV3 (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1748) ]]
  (1) Internal: Failed to call ThenRnnBackward with model config: [rnn_mode, rnn_input_mode, rnn_direction_mode]: 2, 0, 0 , [num_layers, input_size, num_units, dir_count, max_seq_length, batch_size, cell_num_units]: [1, 2048, 2048, 1, 24, 4, 2048]
         [[node tower_0/gradients/tower_0/cudnn_lstm/CudnnRNNV3_grad/CudnnRNNBackpropV3 (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1748) ]]
         [[tower_0/gradients/tower_0/cudnn_lstm/CudnnRNNV3_grad/CudnnRNNBackpropV3/_69]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.
```

Answer (score 1):

Error indicates that you're running out of `GPU` memory. Either remove samples that are too long from your dataset or reduce your `batch size`.

If that doesn't help look at this [thread](https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech/issues/3088), there has been discussion around this known bug (similar to the one you reported) and proposed working solution is to set:

```
TF_CUDNN_RESET_RND_GEN_STATE=1
```

Comment: I've actually seen that thread and tried exporting that ENV variable. The model I am running is actually DeepSpeech as well. I suppose my GPU just can't handle it. I have even tried setting batch size to 1 but yeah it fizzles out after a certain # of steps with the RNN error.

Comment: @Coldchain9 If model itself won't fit on GPU then you can't expect it to work. You should always cross check model requirements against GPU specs. If you further have any pointers/updates on this topic/thread request you to post it here as it could be helpful to others